# Matching filename in ls (bash)

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following files

```
tcpdump-12
tcpdump-12.delay
tcpdump-24
tcpdump-24.delay
```

Is there a way to `ls` only the files

```
tcpdump-12
tcpdump-24
```

I can do

```
ls tcpdump-[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]
```

but I am looking for something more generic that can take any number of digits, something like tcpdump-[0-9]+ if I was using vim or python regular expressions.

Comment: It's not `ls` that does the globbing, it's your shell.

Comment: Be aware that not all shells support the `[[:digit:]]` syntax.  A quick experiment shows that bash, zsh, and dash do, but tcsh and ksh don't (at least by default).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One needs to turn on *extended glob* functionality of bash to be able to use the advanced pattern matching.

```
$ ls
tcpdump-12  tcpdump-12.delay  tcpdump-24  tcpdump-24.delay
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls tcpdump-+([[:digit:]])
tcpdump-12  tcpdump-24
```

Comment: Oooohhh, +1, didn't know about that one, though it's a bit bass-ackward in terms of RE syntax :-)

Comment: It's bash. Bass-ackwardness should not be a huge surprise.

Answer (score 7):

If you're sure that all the unwanted files end with '.delay' you can do this:

```
ls --ignore '*.delay'
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're using `[[:digit:]]` rather than `[0-9]`; are you concerted the file names might contain other kinds of digits?

Most of the other answers are good, but a quick-and-dirty solution is:

```
ls tcpdump-*[0-9]
```

It works for the particular set of files you have, but it would also match file names like `tcpdump-FOO7`.

In a general-purpose script, it's worth the effort to match exactly the pattern you want.  In a one-short interactive shell command, sloppy shortcuts that just happen to work for the current situation can be useful.

Comment: Using `[[:digit:]]` is good practice, especially if you want your code to work on something weird like EBCDIC one day. For a one-off job it's certainly overkill, but don't knock good habits.

Comment: @tripleee: For what it's worth, `[0-9]` matches digits and only digits in EBCDIC as well.  The letters are non-contiguous, but the digits are contiguous.  And not all shells support the `[[:digit:]]` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output from ls into grep.  Grep has an "invert" option (to show lines that don't match), so you could do this:

```
 ls tcpdump-* | grep -v '\.delay$'
```

Comment: Fixed (dropped `*`, added `\` to escape the `.`, added `$` to anchor to end of file name).

Comment: The syntax for doing an actual regex filter (instead of `-v`, which performs an inverse filter), is `-e`, if you're looking.